# write in div issue because of after/before in css

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

I have a code that create a sticky note with html and css. But I have problem when I want to write any thing in yellow area.

```css
#slm {
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align:100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10% 0/0 0 40% 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  positon: relative;
}
#slm:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  positon: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80% 0/0 0 50% 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="slm">
   
      slm<br>
      Hi
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking to do code for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have typo in the style `position`.

Use `absolute` positioning of the text inside the `sticky` area by wrapping it in a div.

```css
#slm {
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align:100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10% 0/0 0 40% 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#slm:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80% 0/0 0 50% 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.text{
      position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 54px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slm">
   <div class="text">
      slm<br>
      Hi
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there's a typo in your code: you've written positon instead of position!

Secondly, you need to define the top & left properties to the "position" rule for both the ID's in your css.

I would then add some padding to the `#slm` element, and reduce some of the width. That should then give you then result you intended:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0wrkzvzp/

```
#slm {
  width: 120px;
  vertical-align:100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10% 0/0 0 40% 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top:0; left:0;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
#slm:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;  
  width: 50px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80% 0/0 0 50% 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a solution like this: https://jsfiddle.net/neya0v76/4/

wrap the text in a `<p>` tag and set it to an `absolute` position like this:

HTML

```
<div id="slm">
  <p>slm<br> Hi</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slm p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `position` instead of `positon`!

It's better to have some container for your texts.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="slm">
  <div class="inner">
    slm
    <br>
    hi
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slm {
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align:100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10% 0/0 0 40% 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#slm:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80% 0/0 0 50% 0;
  background-color: white;
}

#slm .inner{
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jxsrp86t/2/

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```css
#slm {
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align:100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10% 0/0 0 40% 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#slm:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80% 0/0 0 50% 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.text{
  top: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  position: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="slm">
      <div class="text">slm</div>
      <div class="text">hi</div>
</div>
```